# How to add textbox value to array and display only the filled array places?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, textbox, listbox

I have a array, its size is 100. So it is like this:

```
string[] Brands = new string[100];
```

I also have a `TextBox` on my `Form`. Everytime I click the `Button`, I want the `TextBox` to store its data in the array. After that I want the array to display the values into a `ListBox`. But, I only want the `ListBox` to display the actual used memory of the array. So I have 100 places in the array, but I only want to show the used ones.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: this would be simpler using a `List<string>`  lists act like an array... but without the attitude

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So yeah, I need to use the array[100] to show a learning goal. After I've done this, I can use the list method. But first I have to use the array[100].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the restriction, given that you can only use array, what you would probably need is something like this

```
int index = 0; //to tell the current position of the array "pointer"
string[] Brands = new string[100];

//And on your Button click event
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (index < Brands.Length) {
        Brands[index] = textBox1.Text;
        listBox1.Items.Add(Brands[index++]);                
    }
}
```

This way you add whatever is in the `textBox1` at the event `button1` is clicked to the position in the array which is pointed by your `index` value. And as long as your `index` is not greater than the `Brands.Length` you can always add item to your `listBox1` by using `listBox1.Items.Add`.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad to know that. The most important thing is learning the concept along the way. Glad that I can be of any help in your learning process. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
    int ArrayPos = 0;
    string[] Brands = new string[100];

            private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {

             if(arrayPos < 100)
             {
             Brands[ArrayPos] = textBox.Text;
             listbox.add(Brands[ArrayPos]);
             ArrayPos++;

             }


            };
```

This will allow you to add items to the array at the next position as well as checking that the array is not full. Also It will then add the contents of the newly filled array position into the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do will be much easier if you use a `List<string>` instead.

```
List<string> Brands = new List<string>();
```

When you click the button, you can add your element to the list like this:

```
Brands.Add(textBox1.Text);
```

And when you want to show the number of elements (I assume that's what you mean by "actual used memory"), it's as easy as referencing the `Count` property:

```
int totalBrands = Brands.Count;
```

If for some reason you have a constraint that forces you to use a `string[100]`, this won't work.

Comment: Thank you. List would be better indeed. But i'm restricted to use only array[100].